# Communication with iText PDF from Website

Tags: java, itext, frontend, backend

I'm not super familiar with front-end back-end communication so my apologies if I'm asking at too basic of a level.

So I used iText PDF to create a reporting software. Essentially, the user enters data through a Java Swing UI & a report is generated on the Desktop. However, I now want this to be done in a browser. In other words, the user enters the same data in a form on a website and that data is sent to iText PDF Java code I've written and sends back the generated PDF file for the user to be able to download. I've looked for a solution in quite a few places but haven't been able to find what I need so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've already put in a significant amount of work in creating the report from iText PDF so I would like to be able to do it this way. However, if it would be significantly more beneficial to do it some other way, I am always open to suggestions. Thank you so much!

Comment: You should look into JSF, your PDF will be generated by a bean or servlet.

Comment: you send the data to backend, the backend creates a pdf out of that data, and generates a webpage with a link to the pdf file

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a web service which will accept data from a browser, generate PDF and allow a browser to download it. It is easier if your web service has got REST API. You may build web service in Java. Have a look at the following libraries to help you build a web service: Jetty, Play Framework, Jackson.